# T4 code generator for Entity Framework - Failed to resolve include text for EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude

Tags: entity-framework, msbuild, wcf-ria-services, t4, ef-database-first

I'm trying to automate build process for CI server of Silverlight 5 application using OpenRIA Services.

I've got database-first Entity Framework .edmx generated file from which DomainModel is generated, and as part of build I want to generate entities by T4 code generator.

### Project settings

My server `.csproj` changes.

Imports

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />
# Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets are added after CSharp.targets
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets"/>
```

and properties

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
    ...
<PropertyGroup>
```

Installed sdk, and tools:

- [Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=40758)
- [Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Visualization & Modeling SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=40754)
- [Entity Framework 6 Tools for Visual Studio 2012 & 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=40762)

### Broken build

Looks correct, but at build there is such a error

```
5>  Transforming template DomainModel\EntityConverters.tt...
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets(396,5): error : Failed to resolve include text for file:C:\{path to my project}\DomainModel\EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude. Line=-1, Column=-1
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets(396,5): error : Loading the include file 'EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude' returned a null or empty string. The transformation will not be run. . Line=21, Column=4
```

### Suspicious

All `.tt` files has T4 import

```
<#@ include file="EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude"#>
```

I have a suspicion that it's targeting local directory, not even build directory.

I'm curious why `Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets` variable is targeting `EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude` in `{path to my project}` not in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\Templates\Includes` where it really is.
`Loading the include file 'EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude' returned a null or empty string` seems legit according to this path.

Maybe I've missed some setting, import or path set?
How I can change or update path for this utility?

---

Associated Q&A already checked:

- [Transforming T4 Templates On Build by Nico Ploner](http://t4-editor.tangible-engineering.com/blog/transforming-t4-templates-on-build.html)
- [How can I resolve this error: Loading the include file 'EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude' returned a null or empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14999633/how-can-i-resolve-this-error-loading-the-include-file-ef-utility-cs-ttinclude) - install/reinstall of Entity Framework 6 Tool for VS didn't worked
- [Silverlight 4, RIA Services & TFS 2010 Build Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337384/silverlight-4-ria-services-tfs-2010-build-server/7558566#7558566) - it's not this problem, my projects are building in correct order
- [TFS Hosted Build Controller - Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340417/tfs-hosted-build-controller-microsoft-texttemplating-targets-not-found/18340603#18340603) - (for others) that was also a problem, if you're handling T4 automation build it could be usefull

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8210150/615522 or installing Microsoft Web Developer Tools and Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools?

Comment: Instalation of Microsoft Web Developer Tools and Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools didn't helped.
About this question - this is not the case. Event the workaround described in question didn't work in all cases.

Comment: Maybe it is possible to set full path in <#@ include file="..." #>

Answer (score 2):

Problem can be solved by adding absolute or relative path to `EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude` in your T4 file. For build server the best solution is probably to copy files that usualy can be found in path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\Templates\Includes` to your project and then change the line:

```
<#@ include file="EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude"#>
```

to for example:

```
<#@ include file="..\..\EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude"#>
```

For some reason when template transformation is run from MSBuild it looks for `.ttinclude` files in the same location that `.tt` file is.

Comment: But... **WHY?**

Why the default VS installation has problems with files generated by itself?...

Comment: I am not sure that those files were generated by VS but from what I remember problem occurred only in MSBuild, in VS it worked.

Answer (score -1):

I found i was able to keep the include file as

```
<#@ include file="EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude"#>
```

by adding the following to my config

```
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  <connectionStrings>
```

Comment: I'm no longer at the project and those problems, so its hard for me to verify -   can you confirm does it generate entities when run manually from MS Build?